# Separate css style sheet for mobile devices and another for desktop - no media queries

Tags: css, mobile, desktop

I know this type of question has been asked a 1000 times, and 99% of the time someone hurries in and gives media queries as the solution. It no longer is the optimum answer.

The Situation: I have video in the background on a webpage - that does not render on a mobile device, so I want to use an agent to detect mobile and simply swap the css page to a mobile friendly version.

Please do not post a media query as the solution because my cell phone is 800x1200 and my tablet is 1900x1200, more than my desktop:1600x900 so a media query wont work.

Hoping someone can post an entire solution with the agent and insert where the css reference goes becuase I dont want to mess that up..

Im presently using an agent that redirects to a separate mobile page but that means maintaining 2 pages vs. one with stripping css instead. (1 page and 2 css files)

I think many here will find this answer helpful as many with this question have no answer.
thank you.. 
PS - please be detailed Im a noob.
thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/ should do what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, thanks I actually am using that and just need a way to figure redirecting to a css rather than to a web page. yes Im that much of a noob. If i find something that works I will post it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your using http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/ something along the lines of the code below should work.

```
<?php
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if ($detect->isMobile()) 
{
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css">
<?php
}
else
{
?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="noneMobile.css">
<?php
}
?>
```

Very simple example but would work in your case. You could go into more detail with $ddetect->isTablet() etc, full list here http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect

Comment: This works as far as bringing in the style sheet but it places it before the declaration and does not reder the page correctly. Is it because the css link is before the head tag: <`link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css media="screen" "`>
<`!DOCTYPE html`>
<`html lang="en"`>
<`head`>

Comment: ok, this works !!!! If I place the <`?php  include ("detect.php"); ?`> tag in place of where the style sheet link would normally go, it places the link in its place and renders the page correctly. So a very big thank you !! as this worked ! Do you think I can do this swap with div tags as well? thanks again !! This should be helpful for many.

Comment: Yeah put it within the head tags, what do you mean 'swap with div tags' ?

Comment: The entire reason for this needed css for mobile is because I have video running in the background (tubular) which attaches to the id# wrapper div - which displays 100% width and height in the background. Since mobile does not display video in the background, I need to "swap" that wrapper div (to eliminate video) with a div called something else (wrapper-mobile) so the video wont attach to the div called wrapper, then no video will play. - hope that makes sense. thanks again

Comment: something like `<div id="<?php if ($detect->isMobile()) { echo "wrapper-mobile"; } else {echo "wrapper"; } ?>" >content here</div>`

Comment: ok.. gonna fiddle, will reply shortly, thanks again.. so far, desktop works perfect with this div code, mobile is ONLY showing video and no content - the opposite effect.. thanks !!:) will fiddle

Comment: yes !! All of your solutions absolutely worked for me on this ! I can't thank you enough for your help and quick and clear repsonses ! Instead of swapping divs, which work. I swapped out the video jquery link which stops the video issue on mobile entirely. Thanks again, I've been on this a long time ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

In direct defiance of the question, I'm going to say that as of 10/12/21, Media Queries are absolutely an option once again, as in most situations they will work.

If you're looking to target the **page width**, you'll use the following.  This is a quick fix, and most likely is the main reason for OP's question, as it doesn't address the fact that some devices have resolutions shared by desktops, yielding a mobile experience on desktop, or vice-versa.

```
@media (max-width:400px)
```

To circumvent this, you want to use the following to check for the **device width** instead:

```
@media (max-device-width: 400px)
```

This deals with the DISPLAY size, versus the webpage size.  It's not perfect, but combining this with device heights, and vendor-specific queries, you can fix most situations with CSS.  The bonus is that you can keep the web page optimized without needing extra JavaScript or PHP, or any other additional web technology, and for the fringe cases, you can use the options provided here.